# More space needed between tabs bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

http://codebin.org/view/992b5764 (my code)

On my navbar my logo image is overlapped by one of the tabs. Is there any way to give space between the logo and the tabs. Like a horizontal break?

-thanks

Comment: Could you put your code into [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lasquish/s8cm9nop/

Comment: ^Not sure if this is a working fiddle.

Comment: Try changing your image tag to this `<img src="img/logo.png" style="position: relative; top: 10px;" />` switching from position fixed to relative.

Comment: It worked in a sense that the tab is moved over but the image for some reason is pushed down about 100px. How do i move my image back up to the spot it was in before? http://jsfiddle.net/lasquish/s8cm9nop/1/

Comment: I tried creating a <div id="move"> then doing #move {top:10px;} in css but that didnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do this: keep your HTML as is, and then add this to your CSS

```
.navbar-brand{width:200px; display:block;}
```

Be sure to load this AFTER Bootstrap's CSS, or add !important to it. Of course, that 200px width should be the size of your logo, it could be smaller or bigger

You can [see fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/y5wts170/)

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're going for, I suggest you get rid of the `position:fixed...` inline stuff, and add a custom class to the `navbar-brand` div. Then move your logo img around with padding overrides within.

HTML

```
<a class="navbar-brand custom" href="#"><img src="//placehold.it/100x50&text=LOGO" /></a>
```

CSS

```
.custom{padding-top:0px;}
```

DEMO: http://www.bootply.com/Bjlkb7lDeI

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem!